# Swift unable to infer complex closure return type

Tags: ios, swift

I got the error I stated in the title which appears to be in the HStack.

My code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

struct CartView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var cartdata = getCartData()
    @State private var showRow = true
    
    
    var body : some View{
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            Text(self.cartdata.datas.count != 0 ? "Items In The Cart" : "No Items In Cart").padding([.top,.leading])
            
            
            if self.cartdata.datas.count != 0{
                
                List{
                    
                    
                    ForEach(self.cartdata.datas){i in
                        
                        
                        if i.quantity == 0 {
                            let db = Firestore.firestore()
                            db.collection("cart").document(self.cartdata.datas[i.last!].id).delete { (err) in
                                
                                if err != nil{
                                    print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                self.cartdata.datas.remove(atOffsets: i)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 15){
                            
                            CartRow(item: i)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController?.present(textFieldAlertView(id: i.id), animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { (index) in
                        
                        let db = Firestore.firestore()
                        db.collection("cart").document(self.cartdata.datas[index.last!].id).delete { (err) in
                            
                            if err != nil{
                                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                                return
                            }
                            
                            self.cartdata.datas.remove(atOffsets: index)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

What I want do is that if the  quantity of the item equals 0, that it gets deleted from the db and gets removed from my view.

The database is a Firestore database. The self.carddata.datas is an array of the items it reads form the Firestore database.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use that if and action inside View in the ForEach.

You can use it in the `.onAppear` View modifier of the HStack inside the ForEach depending on your Use Case.

Comment: I am new to SWIFT but I suppose onAppear is triggered when the list is shown?

Comment: How can I accomplish this that the item where the quantity is 0 is getting deleted?